# Use AVERAGEIF, MAXIF, etc. based cells already identified by a COUNTIF function

Tags: excel, countif

I have a large rainfall dataset upon which I have already used a relatively complex COUNTIF function to categorize into 56 different categories. The data itself is organized into rows of "events" with columns of other data-points such as duration, total amount, intensity, etc. [This is a brief example of what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBUTZ.png). The categories are organized as a multidimensional table based on duration and return period. [Here is an example of what the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpQeh.png). As the title of the table says, it is just counting the number of storms that fall into each of these categories.

I now want to get some other basic descriptive statistics about the storms that fall into each of those individual groups. I know I could just copy the arguments from the COUNTIF function into new a new MAXIF function, but I have a feeling that would be much more inefficient than is otherwise possible.

Is there a way I can call on the storms already identified by the COUNTIF in each category, and then run other functions such as a MAX or AVERAGE or whatever on some of the other columns in the data such as the "Amount" or "10 min (mm/hr)" intensity, etc? Like I already said, I am no excel wizard and I'm sure I am being very inefficient in this process. So if there is an entirely different way you would go about this, I am all ears.

Comment: There is no way for a formula to refer to the range inside another formula, if that is what you are asking.  COUNTIF does not return a range so its output can not be used either.

Comment: Use if() to put a 1 or 0 or repeat the values according to those same conditions.